# Blocking all porn sites and contents

Tags: applications

Is there anything in android mobile which has block all porn sites with high security features and any paid software or anything please tell me..

Comment: Try searching our website for content/ads blocking. Those solutions can work for your case too. Other than that, Android doesn't come with this specific functionality per se to block adult contents on the go.

Comment: DNS blocking is enough. Works with both rooted and non-rooted devices.

Comment: I need those type of methods or apps which has not uninstall if i want uninstall those things then i can't do ..

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to block porn on android

1- First if you are android pie or up you can use DNS option in settings in other wireless connections and use a DNS that block porn like clean browsing DNS or opendns

Use this DNS

adult-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org

Put it in DNS option on settings

2- via router settings you can block  porn same way like above way by providing DNS to block porn (just Google DNS to block porn and how to inject in router settings)

3- block porn on non root devices by using apps such as blockada or adguard

4 - block porn in root devices by using an app such as adaway with providing a host file to block porn ( just Google adway host to block porn)

5 - there are an XDA app to block porn but don't remember it's name now

https://techwiser.com/block-adult-content-on-android/